# I'm converting column headers in row in my database view having many fields

Tags: sql, database, pivot

I want my column headers to be converted to rows and in front of them data is displayed. Please help if any one knows about it. I tried pivoting but didn't find that much help.

Comment: search google for pivot table

Comment: Pivot seems to be the right approach. Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: It sounds like you need unpivot.

Comment: Wichh DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? DB2?

Answer (score 0):

[sample took from http://technet.microsoft.com/](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2 ;
GO
SELECT DaysToManufacture, AVG(StandardCost) AS AverageCost 
FROM Production.Product
GROUP BY DaysToManufacture;
```

Here is the result set.

```
DaysToManufacture          AverageCost
0                          5.0885
1                          223.88
2                          359.1082
4                          949.4105
```

No products are defined with three DaysToManufacture.
The following code displays the same result, pivoted so that the DaysToManufacture values become the column headings. A column is provided for three [3] days, even though the results are NULL.

```
-- Pivot table with one row and five columns
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Here is the result set.

```
Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days    0         1         2           3       4       
AverageCost                       5.0885    223.88    359.1082    NULL    949.4105
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to unpivot your data.  The process of unpivoting converts multiple columns into multiple rows.  You did not specify what database you are using so I will provide a few solutions.

Let's say you have the following sample data:

```
create table yourtable
(
  id int,
  name varchar(50),
  class1 varchar(50),
  class2 varchar(50),
  class3 varchar(50),
  class4 varchar(50)
);

insert into yourtable
values 
  (1, 'John', 'Science', 'Math', 'Chem', 'Physics'),
  (2, 'Bob', 'Math', 'SS', 'Bio', 'Chem'),
  (3, 'Jim', 'Econ', 'Math', 'Bio', 'Sci'),
  (4, 'Sally', 'Crim', 'Bio', 'Math', 'Chem');
```

If your database does not have an UNPIVOT function like SQL Server, Oracle, then you can use a UNION ALL query to get the result:

```
select id, name, 'class1' col, class1 value
from yourtable 
union all
select id, name, 'class2' col, class2 value
from yourtable 
union all
select id, name, 'class3' col, class3 value
from yourtable 
union all
select id, name, 'class4' col, class4 value
from yourtable;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c0bf/1)

If you are using a database that supports the UNPIVOT function, the syntax of the query will be similar to:

```
select id, name, col, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
    value
    for col in (class1, class2, class3, class4)
) unpiv
```